# Python CSV file input, validation not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, validation

I tried to print out the variable **gayle** and it assigns values correctly.
I can't find why is my program stopping if i input non-existent ID.

```
    os.system("clear")
    print('\tSEARCH AND VIEW FILE\n')
    gayle=0

    file_input = input('Search ID Number: ')
    proj = io.open('all_projects.csv', 'r')        
    while True:
        data = proj.readline()
        if file_input in data:
            txt = data
            gayle += 1
            break
    proj.close()
    
    if gayle > 0:
        list2 = txt.split(",")
        i = Preview(list2)
        i.view()
        print(gayle)
        try_again('Search file again?','Invalid input.',2)
    elif (gayle == 0):
        print("Not exist")
```

Comment: you need to set initial value of `gayle ` to 0 somewhere

Comment: yes, i forgot to include it. But it has gayle=0

Comment: try printing gayle outside of the if condition

Comment: Just clarifying, when you say your program is stopping do you mean it outputs "Not exist" and stops or does it look like your program freezes ? since you dont seem to have any check in your while true loop to break at the end of the file

Comment: i have checked it through printing, and eventually its not stopping. it became infinite loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: You mean why it is _not_ stopping? Rather than use while loop, I'd guess you want to iterate through each line by using eg. `for line in open("all_projects.csv", "r"): ...`

You probably want to take a  look at `csv` module too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only loop over lines in your file you can do this using the `open()` and `readlines()` functions. Change your file reading and loop to the following and it should work

```
proj = open('all_projects.csv', 'r')
Lines = proj.readlines()
proj.close()

for line in Lines:
    if file_input in line:
            txt = data
            gayle += 1
            break
```

Comment: i tried it and it worked! you saved mee thank you so much!